# Probability Question - Can't figure out the answer.

Tags: probability

**Question:** Sophia, Gabriel and Elizabeth take their driving test. The chances that they pass are $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{5}{8}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$ respectively.

a) Find the probability that Sophia passes and the other two fail.

b) By listing the possible outcomes for one of the girls passing and the other two failing, find the probability that exactly one of the three passes.

c) If only one of them passes, find the probability that it is Gabriel.

For part (a) and (b) I got answers $\frac{3}{64}$ and $\frac{17}{64}$ respectively. These answers are correct.

But apparently for part (c) the answer is $\frac{5}{17}$, but I keep getting $\frac{5}{64}$ because $(\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{5}{8}\times\frac{1}{4}) =\frac{5}{64}$ because you only want Gabriel to be the one that passes the test. I can't figure out where I went wrong, I even listed all the outcomes on a tree diagram but I still see no error.

Answer (score 1):

For part (c), recognize the differences between the questions:

- "What is the probability that Gabriel is the only one who passes?"
- "*Given that only one person passed*, what is the probability that that one person is Gabriel?"

In the first question, this might have been written something like $Pr(G=1)$ (*where a value of $1$ is given if the person passes and 0 otherwise*) whereas in the second question this might have been written $Pr(G=1\mid S+G+E=1)$

Now... recall the meaning and definition of *conditional probability*, that $Pr(A\mid B) = \dfrac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}$

To continue your problem, find the probability that only Gabriel passed and take the ratio of that over the probability that exactly one person passed.

> You already calculated both of those probabilities, now you just need to take the ratio

$~$

> $\frac{5/64}{17/64} = \frac{5}{17}$